# Why while loop is sticking at raw_input? (python)

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

In the following code i am trying to make a "more" command (unix) using python script by reading the file into a list and printing 10 lines at a time and then asking user do you want to print next 10 lines (Print More..). 
Problem is that raw_input is asking again and again input if i give 'y' or 'Y' as input and do not continue with the while loop and if i give any other input the while loop brakes.
My code may not be best as am learning python.

```
import sys
import string
lines = open('/Users/abc/testfile.txt').readlines()
chunk = 10
start = 0

while 1:
    block = lines[start:chunk]
    for i in block:
        print i
    if raw_input('Print More..') not in ['y', 'Y']:
        break
    start = start + chunk
```

Output i am getting for this code is:-

```
--
10 lines from file

Print More..y
Print More..y
Print More..y
Print More..a
```

Comment: A side notes: Even after you fix this, the program is going to loop forever once you reach the end. If the file is 100 lines long, `lines[100:110]`, `lines[110:120]`, etc. are all perfectly valid empty lists. You probably want `for line in f:` instead of writing your own explicit loop and counter. Also, why import modules you don't need, and why assign `block` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tim Pietzcker pointed out, there's no need of updating `chunk` here, just use `start+10` instead of `chunk`.

```
block = lines[start:start+10]
```

and update start using `start += 10`.

Another alternative solution using `itertools.islice()`:

```
 with open("data1.txt") as f:
    slc=islice(f,5)            #replace 5 by 10 in your case
    for x in slc:
        print x.strip()
    while raw_input("wanna see more : ") in("y","Y"):     
        slc=islice(f,5)        #replace 5 by 10 in your case
        for x in slc:
            print x.strip()
```

this outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
wanna see more : y
6
7
8
9
10
wanna see more : n
```

Comment: It's not my downvote, but this solution results in the chunk size growing by 10 with every iteration. So I don't quite understand how it can be the accepted answer when it's definitely giving a wrong result. The name `chunk` is misleading...

Comment: Doing `islice` outside the loop and again at the end of each loop still isn't as pythonic as just writing a function that groups into batches of 10 lines.

Comment: @TimPietzcker you're quite right, no need of updating `chunk` here. The solution was wrong and indeed deserved a -1. I wonder why he accepted it.

Comment: @abarnert Just saw your solution and my solution didn't look any `pythonic` at all in front of your alternatives, so a +1 to your answer, and removing the word `pythonic` from my solution.

Comment: It's still much more pythonic than the explicit loop, it's just that you can go farther. (Just like my first attempt.)

Answer (score 5):

You're constructing your slices wrong: The second parameter in a slice gives the stop position, not the chunk size:

```
chunk = 10
start = 0
stop = chunk
end = len(lines)
while True:
    block = lines[start:stop]     # use stop, not chunk!
    for i in block:
        print i
    if raw_input('Print More..') not in ['y', 'Y'] or stop >= end:
        break
    start += chunk
    stop += chunk
```

Comment: Or alternatively just `block = [start : start + chunk]`

Comment: If you like the version by @Deestan better, why not edit your answer to reflect it?

Comment: @abarnert: I guess if I had written this for myself, I would have done so, but using `start` and `stop` makes it more explicit what's happening here.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of explaining why your code doesn't work and how to fix it (because Tim Pietzcker already did an admirable job of that), I'm going to explain how to write code so that issues like this don't come up in the first place.

Trying to write your own explicit loops, checks, and index variables is difficult and error-prone. That's why Python gives you nice tools that almost always make it unnecessary to do so. And that's why you're using Python instead of C.

For example, look at the following version of your program:

```
count = 10
with open('/Users/abc/testfile.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(testfile):
        print line
        if (i + 1) % count == 0:
            if raw_input('Print More..') not in ['y', 'Y']:
                break
```

This is shorter than the original code, and it's also much more efficient (no need to read the whole file in and then build a huge list in advance), but those aren't very good reasons to use it.

One good reason is that it's much more robust. There's very little explicit loop logic here to get wrong. You don't even need to remember how slices work (sure, it's easy to learn that they're `[start:stop]` rather than `[start:length]`… but if you program in another language much more frequently than Python, and you're always writing `s.sub(start, length)`, you're going to forget…). It also automatically takes care of ending when you get to the end of the file instead of continuing forever, closing the file for you (even on exceptions, which is painful to get right manually), and other stuff that you haven't written yet.

The other good reason is that it's much easier to read, because, as much as possible, the code tells you what it's doing, rather than the details of how it's doing it.

But it's still not perfect, because there's still one thing you could easily get wrong: that `(i + 1) % count == 0` bit. In fact, I got it wrong in my first attempt (I forgot the +1, so it gave me a "More" prompt after lines 0, 10, 20, … instead of 9, 19, 29, …). If you have a `grouper` function, you can rewrite it even more simply and robustly:

```
with open('/Users/abc/testfile.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    for group in grouper(testfile, 10):
        for line in group:
            print line
        if raw_input('Print More..') not in ['y', 'Y']:
            break
```

Or, even better:

```
with open('/Users/abc/testfile.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    for group in grouper(testfile, 10):
        print '\n'.join(group)
        if raw_input('Print More..') not in ['y', 'Y']:
            break
```

Unfortunately, there's no such grouper function built into, say, the `itertools` module, but you can write one very easily:

```
def grouper(iterator, size):
    return itertools.izip(*[iterator]*size)
```

(If efficiency matters, search around this site—there are a few questions where people do in-depth comparisons of different ways to achieve the same effect. But usually it doesn't matter. For that matter, if you want to understand *why* this groups things, search this site, because it's been explained at least twice.)