# Python: raw_input asks for input once the first time, then twice

Tags: python, python-idle

I ran across this old piece of code on my PC:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

player_pos = 2

def game():
    global player_pos

    background = [2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
    screen     = [0] * 5

    for i in range(5):
        screen[i] = background[i]

    screen[player_pos] = 7

    print screen

    if raw_input("> ") == 'a':
        player_pos -= 1

    elif raw_input("> ") == 'd':
        player_pos += 1

while True:
    game()
```

I run it from IDLE and the prompt works as expected. However, if you press 'a' or 'd', it may work properly or just print a blank line, and then work properly if you press 'd' again. 
So you need to press 'a' or 'd' once or twice, and I want it to always be once.

I found this question but I don't know how to translate it to my problem. [Simple:Python asks for input twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302085/simplepython-asks-for-input-twice)

Comment: try to never use global variables.

Comment: there's not a lot of translation to do to apply this to your problem.  every time you do `raw_input()` you're prompting the user for input.  instead, store `raw_input` in a variable before your `if` and `elif`, then test the variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why while loop is sticking at raw\_input? (python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267107/why-while-loop-is-sticking-at-raw-input-python)

Comment: in your code, inputing `d` requires inputing anything but `a` first, and then `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `raw_input` method twice - once in each `if` statement.
You could store the user input in a local var and then test it:

```
user_answer = raw_input("> ")
if user_answer == 'a':
    player_pos -= 1
elif user_answer == 'd':
    player_pos += 1
```

Comment: Exactly what i'd post.

Answer (score 0):

Run this step by step:

- `raw_input` is called, the user's input is read.
- this input is compared to `a`.
- if it is not `a`, `raw_input` is called again, the user's input is read.
- this new input is compared to `d`.

As you can see, to input d, you must first not input a, as `raw_input` is called twice.